# how to send datasource parameters to select function

Tags: c#, asp.net

**EDIT**

this is my new try:

now im getting `ObjectDataSource 'MenuDataSource' could not find a non-generic method 'GetData' that has no parameters.`

```
     <asp:ObjectDataSource 
     ID="GridDataSource"            
      SelectMethod="GetData"
      TypeName="Model.GridProvider"
      runat="server"  > 
     <SelectParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="MenuItemID" Type="Int32" DefaultValue="10"  />
      </SelectParameters>
      </asp:ObjectDataSource>


public int DbToAccess
    {
        get
        {
            return SiteMaster.Current_MenuItemID;
        }
    }


[DataObject(true)]
public static class MyMenuProvider
{
        [DataObjectMethod(DataObjectMethodType.Select)]
        public static HierarchicalCollection GetData(int inputMenuItemID)
        {
            return GetCollection(inputMenuItemID);
        }
```

}

how can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

answer is that I am stupid
`TypeName="Model.GridProvider"`
the class i put the select method on was
`MyMenuProvider`

changed to

```
public static class GridProvider
{
    [DataObjectMethod(DataObjectMethodType.Select)]
    public static DataTable GetData(int MenuItemId)
    {
        return GuiCreators.getDataTable("");

    }


    public static void GetCommand(int id)
    {

    }


}
```

and alll my trouble where solved

Answer (score 1):

You could use a public parameter, whose get call goes to the DataSource and gets back it's set parameter. Or even better would be a public parameter that stores it's value in a Session Variable, and both the Select Function and the DataSource access the Parameter.
Something like this:

```
    public string MyParam
    {
           get
           {
                 return Session["MyParamStr"].ToString();
           } 
           set 
           {
                Session["MyParamStr"] = value;
           }
    }
```

Then in your Markup

```
    <asp:Parameter value='<%# MyParam %>' />
```

Comment: I tried this. but when calling source.Select();it gives me exception that it cannot find none generic select function with no parameteres. and I odn;t see the parameters in the source parameter list.

Comment: Hmm, do you need to use an ObjectDataSource? Could you write your own DataAccess class to go to the database, retrieve the result and databind it yourself. Not a fix to your problem, but I only use those asp:DataSources, when they're really straightforward. Once you need access to the parameters I find it better to do your data access in the code behind

Comment: eh might do that tommorow I guess. im new in asp.net and have no idea how to do stuff.